# Which Distribution Is This?

Tags: probability

> On the first day of the week a man has $5$ clean shirts in is closet. Every morning he puts on a shirt and at the end of the day he takes it off and returns it to the closet. Let $X$ be the day that he wore a dirty shirt for the first time. Find the probability function of $X$, and find the day with the highest probability that he will wear a dirty shirt for the first time.

What I did is just calculating when $P(X=3)=\frac{4}{5}*\frac{2}{5}=\frac{8}{25}$

Rather than calcultating is the a distribution that can match?

Comment: ?? Last day, obviously.

Comment: Can be second last day even. There's an equal chance for both days.

Comment: Sorry all, my mistake edited the question

Comment: "the day with the highest (probability)" First day, obviously.

Comment: $P(X=n\text{th day})=\frac{n}{5}$, where $0\leq{n}\leq5$.

Comment: "the day with the highest possibility he will wear a dirty shirt for the first time", Sorry all, I am translating the question from another language.
Will double check next time

Comment: There is missing a very important information: On how days must a shirt been worn to be called "dirty"? If you put on a shirt at day 1 and jump into a pool of mud 5 minutes later, you are wearing a dirty shirt at day 1. But if you pay attention and don't sweat too much, the shirt can be clean even after been worn for a whole week.

Comment: "What distribution should I use" is not really the best question. Start to calculate. The probability of CD is $\frac{1}{5}$. The probability of CCD is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{2}{5}$. Continue.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast once wore it is dirty

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, that what I did, I meant is there a distribution that match this situation

Comment: I do not know a named distribution for this random variable.  It and relatives may be of applied interest (tagged fish). Sorry about the wrong implication you had not calculated. All too often people assume there is a formula for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probabilities can be calculated by the following formula:

$$P(X=x)=\frac{x-1}{5}\prod_{i=0}^{x-2} \frac{5-i}{5}\quad \forall \ x\in \{2,...,6 \}$$

where $x$ is the $n$th day when he wears a dirty shirt for the first time.

**Remark:**

The formula can be simplified to

$$P(X=x)=\frac{x-1}{5^x}\cdot \frac{5!}{(6-x)!}\quad \forall \ x\in \{2,...,6 \}$$